# Bootstrap Vue How to get a height of the card

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the card component in bootstrap-vue. I want to get the height of the card after it is rendered since the height changes based on the amount of text in it. What would be a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `watch` on your model.

```
watch : {
    'modelThatChanges'() {
        var height = document.getElementById("idOfCard").offsetHeight; // includes border and padding
        console.log(height)
    }
}
```

If this gives an issue that it presents the last value and not the new height. You have to do a `Vue.nextTick` and it will look like:

```
watch : {
    'modelThatChanges'() {
        Vue.nextTick(() => {
            var height = document.getElementById("idOfCard").offsetHeight; // includes border and padding
            console.log(height)
        });
    }
}
```